# What should I Learn? Python 2 or python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I know this question has been asked many times on this site. But, time has changed. They've been asked long ago and I guess I could start with  python 3 now? What do you say?
**Python 2.x or 3? and also explain why?** Thanks for any support. :)

Comment: if you know 2, 3 is just more convenient for many things. Start with 2.7

Comment: It really depends (as in, is very subjective) - it depends on what libraries you want to use, what you'll be doing with it, etc.

Comment: Python 2.6+ and 3 are very similar. If you 'know' one then you'll know the other barring a few changes .. (-1 and a Close Vote; see the FAQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can learn either, python 2.x and python 3 are syntactically similar and the knowledge you gain will usually apply to either version.  So just pick one and [dive in](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/)!

As for which you should *use*, the answer is - as usual - it depends.  We can't answer that without knowing what you intend to use python for, as things depends heavily on which 3rd-party libraries you may want to make use of.

Comment: I've no aim. I've few days of holidays and I thought it would be good if I start learning with Python.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much dependent on the context you want to use it for.  There are a number of older modules, even ones still being worked on and supported by their communities, that work on Python 2 but are not yet compatible with Python 3 - a very notable case is [**Pygame**](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).  They may claim otherwise from time to time, but their support of Python 3 is very much a sketchy work-in-progress.  As such, if you are dependent on certain external modules, Python 2 is a very safe choice to keep backwards compatibility with everything.